# CSS 3d transforms on Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Is there anyway to apply a 3d transform (rotates, perspective, etc) in JQuery without having to rely on CSS?

If so, how?

Comment: Nope, not without setting CSS properties.

Comment: Whoever voted to close for that reason really needs to explain how that reason applies to this question.

Comment: This question is nonsense. jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, with some additional tools like animation, ajax, etc. It cannot do anything that Javascript or CSS is not able to do, so you cannot apply transforms in jQuery that are not CSS transforms, it simply does not make sense. It is also unclear what this question is asking. Query for jQuery plugins (offtopic)? An explanation on how to use the .css() method (already answered)?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The basic thing is that it would be hard to do that with jQuery. CSS3 has a transform property. To change the visual appearance of the element you can use that, as it would be simple and fast.

Here is the link for that: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

**How to do that in CSS:**

```
transform:rotate(30deg);
```

Use it as the CSS property. It will rotate the whole element by 30 degree!

**How to do that in jQuery:**

This is the basic code:

```
$('#selector').rotate(30);
```

Use it in function, or anywhere! It will work. But still it is using the CSS `rotate(30)` property. As they have defined the usage of it in JavaScript `object.style.transform="rotate(30deg)"`. There is just a slight change in both the codes, but one is CSS and other is jQuery.

Answer to your question would be: You can do that without using CSS selectors or properties, jQuery almost relies in CSS selectors. This rotate and transform is also completed or done, by the help of CSS! So you will need CSS. I would prefer them both; CSS and jQuery.

Comment: There is no `rotate` method in jQuery. Maybe you are using a plugin?

Comment: No there isnt a rotate method. That was a scratch method! I have mentioned that he should use .css() to use this rotate feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

You could do everything as images on a `<canvas>`, but it would be significantly more complicated, less well supported and less accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Its almost a No. You will always require some CSS selectors or CSS properties to work with jQuery. As far as not relying on CSS is concerned, the answer again will be a NO. You will require the selector for that element. Then you will require a property for that, and CSS3 and CSS already have that! Tranform, Transition, they are all CSS and CSS3 properties.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution you may find will be much more difficult than using CSS, but there's a chance you can get what you need using WebGL.

Comment: I was asking for compatibility purposes, so WebGL would be no good either. Thanks anyway ;)